# JavaScript - How do I fix this rock/paper/scissors game? Not able to use two variables in an if/else if/else statement

Tags: javascript, function, variables, compare

> 

```
<button type="button" onclick="rockPaperScissors()">Click Me!</button><br />

<h3>Player 1: <span id="rps1"></span></h3>
<h3>Player 2: <span id="rps2"></span></h3>
<h3><span id="winner"></span></h3>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function rockPaperScissors() {
        var rps1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
        if (rps1<=33) {
            document.getElementById("rps1").innerHTML = "Rock";
            rps1 = "Rock";
        } else if (rps1<=66) {
            document.getElementById("rps1").innerHTML = "Paper";
            rps1 = "Paper";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("rps1").innerHTML = "Scissors";
            rps1 = "Scissors";
        }
        var rps2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
        if (rps2<=33) {
            document.getElementById("rps2").innerHTML = "Rock";
            rps2 = "Rock";
        } else if (rps2<=66) {
            document.getElementById("rps2").innerHTML = "Paper";
            rps2 = "Paper";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("rps2").innerHTML = "Scissors";
            rps2 = "Scissors";
        };

        if (rps1==rps2) {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "It's a draw!";
        } else if (rps1=="Rock" && rps2=="Paper") {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!";
        } else if (rps1=="Paper" && rps2=="Rock") {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!";
        } else if (rps1=="Rock" && rps2=="Scissors") {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!";
        } else if (rps1=="Scissors" && rps2=="Rock") {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!"; 
        } else if (rps1=="Scissors" && rps2=="Paper") {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!"; 
        } else {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!"; 
        }
        document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = " ";
        };
</script>
```

That is the full code (not including head/html tags etc). I am running it so that when the user clicks a button, two values (rock/paper/scissors) are randomly generated. It's working fine with that, but my *compare()* function doesn't appear to have any output at all... before I edited it, it was just saying *"Player 2 Wins!*, the *else* result.

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Check the very last line.

Comment: Thank you! Works now :) Appreciate it haha, I didn't know why I had it there.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8z4UX/1/)

I removed the very last line and added some more parentheses () to the if statements.

```
function rockPaperScissors() {
var rps1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
if (rps1 <= 33) {
    document.getElementById("rps1").innerHTML = "Rock";
    rps1 = "Rock";
} else if (rps1 <= 66) {
    document.getElementById("rps1").innerHTML = "Paper";
    rps1 = "Paper";
} else {
    document.getElementById("rps1").innerHTML = "Scissors";
    rps1 = "Scissors";
}
var rps2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
if (rps2 <= 33) {
    document.getElementById("rps2").innerHTML = "Rock";
    rps2 = "Rock";
} else if (rps2 <= 66) {
    document.getElementById("rps2").innerHTML = "Paper";
    rps2 = "Paper";
} else {
    document.getElementById("rps2").innerHTML = "Scissors";
    rps2 = "Scissors";
};

if (rps1==rps2) {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "It's a draw!";
} else if ((rps1 == "Rock") && (rps2 == "Paper")) {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!";
} else if ((rps1 == "Paper") && (rps2 == "Rock")) {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!";
} else if ((rps1 == "Rock") && (rps2 == "Scissors")) {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!";
} else if ((rps1 == "Scissors") && (rps2 == "Rock")) {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!";
} else if ((rps1 == "Scissors") && (rps2 == "Paper")) {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!";
} else {
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!";
}
```

}

Comment: It turned out that it was the last line and not the parentheses. Thanks though, appreciate the help :)